# Validity of the law $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am reading the Law of Total Expectation , and came across the following law $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Now I have read the proof of the theorem and sort of understood it. But my question is that the very theorem seems odd because $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is a random variable and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is a number.

So what the law says that a random variable is equal to a number. How does that work out ?

Comment: It's not $\operatorname E(Y\mid X) = \operatorname E(Y),$ but rather $\operatorname E(\operatorname E(Y\mid X)) = \operatorname E(Y). \qquad$

Comment: Here is an intuitive argument: When $X$ is independent of $Y$, knowledge of $X$ (e.g. knowing that $X=2$ for example) provides no information about $Y$ whatsoever. Nowq your original best guess of $Y$ without any prior information (in the $L^2$ sense) is $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ (a constant). When you add $X$ to the mix, which is essentially adding no information, then $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ (the best guess of $Y$ given knowledge of $X$) remains $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ because $X$ adds no information. Thus, the best guess is the constant random variable $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: rubikscube09 I understood the infinitive argument . But was not sure on the analytical argument . Thx anyway for the explanation. @OliverDiaz thx for the explanation. I have still not started measure theory , will come back to the answer when I start it .

Comment: @OliverDiaz : But that is not the law of total expectation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: The OP's question is about the identity $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$ (a.s. is my addition) when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I agree that is not the same as  law of total expectation that states $E[E[Y|X]]=E[Y]$ regardless of what the joint distribution if $X$ and $Y$ are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it is true that $E[Y|X]=E[Y]$ although equality is  almost surely (a.s), i.e., the set where it is not valid has probability $0$.

Here is the argument:

For simplicity assume $X$ is real valued.
Suppose $A\in \sigma(X)$,then $A=X^{-1}(B)$ for some Borel set $B$. Then
$$\begin{align}
E[Y \mathbb{1}_A]&=E[Y\mathbb{1}_B(X)]=E[Y]E[\mathbb{1}_B(X)]\\
&=E[Y]\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=E[Y]\mathbb{P}[A]
\end{align}$$
where the second identity I the first row above is due to the assumption of independence.

Since the constant map $\omega\mapsto E[Y]$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, it follows from the definition (and uniqueness) of conditional expectation that $E[Y|X]=E[X]$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of '$\mathbb{E}[X]$' being a constant is simple.

Alternatively one could (which I think is an excellent way to think about random variables) *define* $\mathbb{E}[X] : = \mathbb{E}[X  | \{ \emptyset,\Omega \}]$ . I.E the conditional expectation on the trivial sigma algebra

Notice the RHS is $\{\emptyset , \Omega\}$ measurable and so is a constant. Likewise the LHS is a constant.

Think of $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{A}]$ as "the best guess of $X$ given we understand $\mathcal{A}$" and so intuitively if $X$ and $Y$ are independent your 'best guess' of $X$ doesn't change at all and you are stuck where you were before simply guessing on the trivial sigma algebra.